# No ObservableObject of type found

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to quick access a list with favourite items from the master view with a modal sheet. The favourite objects are kept in an `EnvironmentObject` array. In the modal sheet there is a button, where you can basically add/remove the object from the favourites list. However, when you remove an item, the `EnvironmentObject` gets empty and the app crashes:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No `ObservableObject` of type `FavouritesList` found.

In the log it says:

> A `View.environmentObject(_:)` for `FavouritesList` may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file

How do I ensure it goes back to the `ContentView` naturally?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var favouriteList: FavouritesList
    @State private var presentingSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: JudgementsView()) {
                    Text("Judgements")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: SecondaryView()) {
                    Text("Secondary acts")
                }
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack {
                        if favouriteList.items.isEmpty {
                            Text("Nothing favoured")
                        } else {
                            ForEach(favouriteList.items, id: \.self) { id in
                                VStack {
                                    HStack {
                                        ForEach(judgementsTAXraw.filter {
                                            $0.id == id
                                        }) { judgement in
                                            NavigationLink(destination: FileViewer(file: judgement.id)) {
                                                Button(judgement.title) {
                                                    self.presentingSheet = true

                                                }.sheet(isPresented: self.$presentingSheet) {
                                                    ModalSheet(file: judgement.CELEX)

                                                }
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                    HStack {
                                        ForEach(secondaryTAXraw.filter {
                                            $0.id == id
                                        }) { secondary in
                                            NavigationLink(destination: FileViewer(file: secondary.id)) {
                                                Text(secondary.title).padding()
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }

                                }


                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Test"))
        }
    }
}

struct ModalSheet: View {
    var file: String

    @State private var showCopySheet = false

    @EnvironmentObject var favouriteList: FavouritesList
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Modal").navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showCopySheet = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "doc.on.doc").frame(minWidth: 40)
                }.actionSheet(isPresented: $showCopySheet) {
                    ActionSheet(title: Text("What do you want to do?"), buttons: [
                        .destructive(Text("favText"), action: {
                            if let index = self.favouriteList.items.firstIndex(of: self.file) {

                                self.favouriteList.items.remove(at: index)


                            } else {
                                self.favouriteList.items.append(self.file)

                            }
                        }),
                        .cancel()
                    ])
                }.frame(minWidth: 50)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to pass your favouriteList to ModalSheet like environmentObject
try

```
ModalSheet(file: judgement.CELEX).environmentObject(favouriteList)
```

Comment: I've had the same issue in the past. For whatever reason, sheets do not inherit the environment of the view that presents them. You must always manually pass in the environment variables.