# SwiftUI Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type " " found and @EnvironmentObject error: may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Details about goal**: I want to fetch data from firebase, list the data in rows in the format of question and answer. The answer will have a textfield to update it. There is a save button that will save the answers by uploading the question and answers to firebase.

**Expectation vs results:**
Expected a button in my main menu when tapped to navigate to the screen. The result is my app freezes, and in the console I get the following error.

**Error**

```
Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros/Monoceros-39.4.4/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55
2020-01-24 13:21:25.523326-0600 FirebaseStarterApp[5025:894100] Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass found.
A View.environmentObject(_:) for AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Monoceros/Monoceros-39.4.4/Core/EnvironmentObject.swift, line 55
```

**My Thoughts**
I'm not too sure where to start but I think it has to do with having to add the environment object to the preview and do something in App Delegate. I have seen somethings about Scene Delegate but I only have App Delegate, I'm not sure if there is a difference

**What I have tried**
I have tried to look at the following links but they did not help for my case [SwiftUI @EnvironmentObject error: may be missing as an ancestor of this view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743004/swiftui-environmentobject-error-may-be-missing-as-an-ancestor-of-this-view)

[No ObservableObject of type found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59619439/no-observableobject-of-type-found)

Here is my code for the **SwiftUI Screen**

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
final class AllJobDataClass: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var allJobDataArray = [JobInfo]()
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
final class AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var questionsAndAnswersInfoArray = [QuestionAndAnswer]()
}

@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
struct SingleQuestionAndAnswerRow: View {

     @State var singleQuestionAndAnswerVar: QuestionAndAnswer

     var body: some View {

       return HStack{
             Text("\(singleQuestionAndAnswerVar.question)")

             TextField("Enter some text", text: $singleQuestionAndAnswerVar.answer)
                 .border(Color.black)
         }
     }
}


@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
struct NewQuestionsScreenSwiftUIView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var allJobDataVar: AllJobDataClass
    @EnvironmentObject var allQuestionsAndAnswerVar: AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass

    init()
    {
        fetchDataFromFirebase()
    }

    var body: some View {
        ScreenBackground
        {
            List(self.allQuestionsAndAnswerVar.questionsAndAnswersInfoArray) { questionAndAnswer in
                    //here is where questionAnswerRow is presented
                SingleQuestionAndAnswerRow(singleQuestionAndAnswerVar: questionAndAnswer)

                }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.endEditingFunction()
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0.0, *)
struct NewQuestionsScreenSwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewQuestionsScreenSwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

My code for **App Delegate**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Window setup
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ATCClassicLandingScreenViewController(nibName: "ATCClassicLandingScreenViewController", bundle: nil))
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

You have declarations for environment objects as

```
struct NewQuestionsScreenSwiftUIView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var allJobDataVar: AllJobDataClass
    @EnvironmentObject var allQuestionsAndAnswerVar: AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass
```

but you must inject them somewhere before `NewQuestionsScreenSwiftUIView` usage, say on creation (or implicitly via parent view). In provided code it is not visible where you create `NewQuestionsScreenSwiftUIView()`, but in that place it should be something like

```
NewQuestionsScreenSwiftUIView()
    .environmentObject(AllJobDataClass()) // < or instance if created before
    .environmentObject(AllQuestionsAndAnswersClass()) // < or instance if created before
```

Comment: In several projects where I've set an observable object into the environment of a view I still get (for example): Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type MazeDocument found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for MazeDocument may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0. The view was created via an ancestor view in the makeWindowControllers() override within the NSDocument; I did check and it didn't help if I delayed the code within makeWindowcontrollers async by 0.25 sec. Any ideas why it can't be seen even with an .environmentObject call in the view hierarchy?

Comment: I would, but I've restructured the code to (successfully) use ObservableObject and Published, so I don't easily have the example to post. Thanks for looking, though - I was mostly hoping there was a generic answer known